# Referencing max/min int in set for c++

Tags: c++, function, set

Say that I have the following example using a set in c++:

```
set <int> a;
for (int i = 0; i <10; i++){
//Assume i is a random number
a.insert(i);
}
```

How can you find the maximum and minimum values for the set example shown above? Ideally I thought that the following would work but it gives the following error:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>' to 'int' in assignment
```

I'm using the following functions to try getting max/min:

```
min = a.begin();
max = a.end();
```

Comment: `a.end()` is not the last element.

Comment: `*a.begin()` and `*a.rbegin()` (note dereference).

Comment: The function begin() returns an iterator to the first element of the set.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all, `begin` and `end` return iterators, which you need to perform indirection on (`*`) to get the element they point at.

Secondly, `end` returns the past-the-end iterator, so doesn't actually refer to the last element. You can instead use the reverse begin iterator.

```
min = *a.begin();
max = *a.rbegin();
```

Answer (score 10):

`a.begin()` and `a.end()` are iterators, not elements. Use

```
min = *a.begin();
```

to receive min element and

```
max = *a.rbegin();
```

to receive max.

```
max = *a.end();
```

will not work because it points on the next element after the last one. So it will return garbage.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, an iterator (as the one returned by `begin()` or `rbegin()`) must be dereferenced to retrieve the value it points to.

But, before dereferencing, the iterator must be checked for validity. For example, on an empty vector `begin()` will return an out-of-range iterator (pointing one position past the last).

So, a more cautious way would be:

```
// assuming a is a vector<int>
vector<int>::const_iterator p = a.cbegin(); // or use auto to hide iterator type
int min_val = p != a.cend()? (*p) : (INT_MAX); // if empty, yield a special value like INT_MAX
```